# Finding the closest time from an array

Tags: javascript, date

I have an object array which looks like this

```
var OGArray = [
 { time: '16:33:53', import_today: '1.10' },
 { time: '16:28:20', import_today: '1.10' },
 { time: '16:23:07', import_today: '1.10' }]
```

The time automatically updates from an API. I also have an array that looks like this

```
var timeArray = ['16:00:00', '16:30:00', '17:00:00', '17:30:00']
```

I want to be able to look at the timeArray[0] and find the closest time match from OGArray.time and then pull what the import_today is

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: I wish all comments were as thoughtful, helpful, and kind as T.J.'s.

Comment: what is "closest" like `'16:30:00'`  would that be `'16:28:20'` or `'16:33:53'`

Comment: Are the `OGArray` entries sorted by the `time` field?

Comment: @epascarello Literally which ever is closest to '16:30:00'. in this case it would be '16:28:20'. It doesnt matter which side of '16:30:00' the time is. As long as its the closest

Comment: @vsemozhebuty because of the way I push the objects into the OGArray, they are automatically sorted by time. the first entry is always the closest to current time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a small helper to convert time to a common base, say seconds, then compare the absolute differences between the times in the two arrays. [*Array.prototype.reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) can help to get the one with the lowest difference.

I don't know how you intend to call this or what actual result you want, but here's one way to get the closest object in *OGArray* for each element in *timeArray*. Once you have the closest object, you can do what you want with it.

It's a little more efficient than using a Date object, but loops through every element in *OGArray* for each element in *timeArray*. If the elements are sorted, then it can be optimised a little by using a loop instead of *reduce* and breaking as soon as *diff* starts to increase.

If *OGArray* is really large (say more than 1,000 elements) and sorted by time, you might use a binary search to find the closest element. That way you do no more than 10 to 20 searches even if the array is 1,000,000 elements or so.

```js
function timeToSecs(time) {
  let [h, m, s] = time.split(':');
  return h*3.6e3 + m*60 + s*1;
}

var OGArray = [
  { time: '16:33:53', import_today: '1.10' },
  { time: '16:28:20', import_today: '1.10' },
  { time: '16:23:07', import_today: '1.10' }
];

var timeArray = ['16:00:00', '16:30:00', '17:00:00', '17:30:00']

// For each element in timeArray
timeArray.forEach(time => {
  let secs = timeToSecs(time);
  let closest = null;
  // Find closest element in OGArray
  OGArray.reduce((acc, obj, i) => {
    let diff = Math.abs(timeToSecs(obj.time) - secs);
    if (diff < acc) {
      acc = diff;
      closest = obj;
    }
    return acc;
  }, Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
  // Display result
  console.log('Time   : ' + time + 
            '\nClosest: ' + JSON.stringify(closest)); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is just a loop over and you do the calculation to what time is closer and you store it. Pick the one that is less.

Below is not the most efficient code, but it works.

```js
var OGArray = [
 { time: '16:33:53', import_today: '1.10' },
 { time: '16:28:20', import_today: '1.10' },
 { time: '16:23:07', import_today: '1.10' }]

var timeArray = ['16:00:00', '16:30:00', '17:00:00', '17:30:00']

var closestArray = timeArray.map(t => {
  const ts = new Date(`01/01/2022 ${t}`);
  return OGArray.reduce((closest, item) => {
    const dC = Math.abs(new Date(`01/01/2022 ${closest.time}`) - ts);
    const dI = Math.abs(new Date(`01/01/2022 ${item.time}`) - ts);
    return dC < dI ? closest : item;
  });
})

console.log(closestArray);
```

Comment: This works and displays OK in a browser console, but displays some weirdness for the last two elements in the SO console. Any ideas?